# Next JS DockerFile for Cloud Build in GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, next.js, dockerfile

This is the recommended Dockerfile from the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment)

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

It takes about 8min to build right now, it was 6 plus something at the beginning.

I'm deploying it into GCP using a Cloud Build pipeline which trigger is a push to a given branch and just wondering the reason to add three different runs of node:alpine.
At the end it will be triggered anytime some push happen in the given branch so it will need to re-create everything.

Shouldn't something like this work better for those building it outside Vercel or similar?

```
FROM node:14.17-alpine AS deps
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn build && yarn install --production
COPY  /app/next.config.js ./
COPY  /app/public ./public
COPY  --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY  /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY  /app/package.json ./package.json

RUN npx next telemetry disable

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

It's not working and I'm trying to make it work like that to see results but in the meantime I would like to get help on figuring out if there's any issue in my mental workaround about that, I'm not an expert on that so I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's faster is because at the point where you do your `yarn build`, the only file you've copied into the image is package.json. The original Dockerfile has copied everything, so it can actually build your app.

As for the multi-stage nature of the first Dockerfile, I think its main advantage is that the final image only contains the output of the build. With a single-stage build like the latter file, the image will contain both the source files and the built files.

Comment: Yes I know the reason to be faster, the question is if I can get it maybe in two steps instead on three (for example building everything on 1 and only copying the output folder and desired files as output on the second) or getting a single step and then get rid of all what I don't want on production (which I suspect not to be much faster than the 2 step idea)

Comment: With my, admittedly very limited, knowledge of nextjs, I would think that things like getStaticProps and getStaticPaths need to run at build time, so it's important that the build process has all the source to look at?

Comment: for the build it is, but then you'll get an output that you can deploy normally. If it were a VPS instance I'll simply build in one runner and then RSYNC the .next folder + the desired files (next.config and so on) with the server and that's it. The difference here is that we use K8s so we "deploy a docker"